# Google Analytics Include Filter Regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

We have an Include Hostname filter set up and working. However, our website now uses so many domains that we've exceeded GA's 255 character limit. What regex would capture all hostnames? So holiday.example.com plus dumbsite.example.com as well as example.com?

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't combining them already, then you could try something like this:

```
(holiday\.|dumbsite\.|^)example\.com
```

Comment: Right, that's what we currently do. However, we now have so many hostnames that using that method exceeds the character limit in GA so we need a new solution.